# SignalR doesn't work with Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have Windows 10 operating system and installed Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers. I try to build an app with SignalR notification system in asp.net MVC. When I run my application under Firefox, everything works fine. But under Internet Explorer and Google Chrome it doesn't work. 
What I found when debbuging is that when the change in my DataBase is made, the application does execute correctly following method:

```
    private void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
            sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;

            var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2);

            RegisterNotification(dt);
        }
    }
```

But when gets to

```
notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
```

the JavaScript which is following:

```
          notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
            if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
                updateNotificationCount();
            }
        }
```

does not react, wheras under Firefox it reacts.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that your code is failing to make it's hub connection within Chrome and IE.  Might be worth checking the the console within the failing browsers to see if there is an error recorded.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Was there an error? :)

Comment: I added    var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log('Notification hub started');
            }); and there is information in console "Notification hub started"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
It turned out I had to add one line in my NotificationHub class:

```
[HubName("notificationHub")]
```

Now it looks following and this solved my problem.

```
[HubName("notificationHub")]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    //public void Hello()
    //{
    //    Clients.All.hello();
    //}
}
```